# Firefox - Google fonts, greek won't work with Roboto

Tags: css, html, firefox, google-font-api, roboto

you can check the following snippet, the issue is that Roboto will not show properly on firefox on greek characters.

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<h1>This is a test</h1>
<h1>Αυτό είναι ένα τεστ</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you need to add the correct subsets to the font API call. Try using this instead

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,greek-ext,greek
```

This appeared to work for me in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the subset "greek" (I added greek extended too just in the case)

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,greek-ext,greek' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<h1>This is a test</h1>
<h1>Αυτό είναι ένα τεστ</h1>
```

**P.S. -** How can you do this automatically?

In step 2 [**here**](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto)